# PDFTK on plesk (centos)

Tags: plesk, pdftk

I'm trying to use PDFTK on a php page hosted on a PLESK server (Centos) but I have an error...

PDFTK was successfully installed with composer

If I use :

```
$pdf = new Pdf('form.pdf');
$result = $pdf->fillForm([
    'name'=>'test name',
    'email' => 'test email',
])
->needAppearances()
->saveAs('form_filled.pdf');
```

I have this error:

```
sh: pdftk: command not found
```

I think I found an idea in the documentation :
With Plesk (onCentos), I think you need to indicate the full path of pdftk, but I don't know how to find it...

```
$pdf = new Pdf('/path/my.pdf', [
    'command' => '/some/other/path/to/pdftk',
    // or on most Windows systems:
    // 'command' => 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe',
    'useExec' => true,  // May help on Windows systems if execution fails
]);
```

Could someone help me or have another idea... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

the php-pdftk composer package doesn't install the pdktk binary for you. You need to install it yourself. From the doc

> Requirements
>
> - The pdftk command must be installed and working on your system

https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk#requirements

Comment: Well done, it was just that, I had missed it! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Steps for installation on CentOS are: `yum install epel-release`, then `yum install pdftk`